# TypeScript command class can not store static variable and access it on the next call

Tags: typescript, undefined

My class extends `Command` and i'm creating a `static User: string` member.

After my remote call, I store the returned string to that variable

When I try to access it from the cli  again, the variable is `Undefined` although I stored it.

this is my class:

```js
class CustomCLI extends Command {

  static User: string

  static flags = {

    connect: flags.string({
      char: 'c'
    }),

    user: flags.boolean({
      char: 'u'
    })
  }

  async run() {

    if (flags.connect) {
      //do stuff and store to 
      CustomCLI.User = "Returned String"
      //Access Given to Admin
    }

    if (flags.user) {
      //do stuff and store to 
      console.log(CustomCLI.User) //this is undefined
    }

  }

}
```

### Execution example

### [image]

Comment: No variables are stored between separate runs (that is - separate runs of your console application). If you want to persist values between runs - you have to explicitly store them in a file or some other storage (and read them from there).

Comment: What would be the best practice for that?

Comment: Not sure about best practice but you can use a library like this: https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist

Comment: hmm , if the get stored locally then the information could be accessed